# Pig Latin translator using a While Loop in Javascipt

Tags: javascript, string, while-loop

My son is teaching himself JavaScript. (He’s too young to have an account here.) He’s trying to write a Pig Latin translator using a “while loop.” The basic question he right now is how to sequence the code - so the user types in the word, then the program translates it, then the result appears in the alert box. He’s brand new to this, so if anyone has any friendly feedback it would be much appreciated.

Here’s what he’s got:

```html
<HTML>

<HEAD>

  <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript">
    <!-- Beginning of JavaScript -
  </SCRIPT>

</HEAD>

<BODY bgcolor="Blue">

  <h3> Type some text then click TRANSLATE. </h3>

  <FORM>
    <INPUT NAME="wordToTranslate" TYPE=Text>
    <INPUT NAME="submit" TYPE=Button VALUE="TRANSLATE" onClick="alert(form.wordToTranslate.value)" style="font-size:1em;background:lime">
  </FORM>
  <script>
    while (wordToTranslate.substring(0, 1) = bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz) {
      console.log(var wordWithoutFirstLetter = wordToTranslate.slice(0, 1);
          var wordWithoutLastLetters = wordToTranslate.slice(1) var wordToTranslate = wordWithoutFirstLetter + wordWithoutLastLetters;
          ++

          wordToTranslate + ay
  </script>
```

Comment: First thing to do is open up the Developer Tools of the browser (usually F12 brings it up) and learn to love the Console tab. It will show the errors. Here on Stack Overflow, clicking Run code snippet shows them too. Learning to use the debugger is the other key tool to learn; it allows you to step through the code line by line and examine the state of variables after each step -- a great way to learn how code works. Finally, there are vast numbers of tutorial sites out there (Stack Overflow is not one of them); use those first. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Oh my, there are a lot of errors in this code. I would really recommend trying some easier examples first. But to save you some time in the future, here are (some) of the issues I see in your JavaScript. Every one of these will cause an error and stop the code from running.

- The primitive strings are not inside quotation marks or apostrophes (for instance, `bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz` should be `"bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"`)
- Attempting to log syntax rather than a string (or object that can be converted to a string): `console.log(var ...)` will cause an error
- Using an increment (++) operator on a string variable...
- some parentheses are missing closing parentheses, and the curly bracket has not closing curly bracket
- you never actually get the string to use from the HTML element (i.e., the "value" of the `<INPUT>`).

After working with some easier examples first and building up to this, I would suggest googling a JavaScript pig latin example and using it as a reference to learn the more complicated concepts (like matching the first letter to a consonant). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looking for general help, I would gently suggest that if he's learning JavaScript and HTML that he learn the newer versions, namely HTML5 , ES6+, and CSS3.

Below is essentially what he has so far--Pig Latin translation code not included--but moved to the newer standards.

```js
'use strict';

const btnTrans = document.getElementById('btnTrans');
const txtWord = document.getElementById('txtWord');

btnTrans.addEventListener('click', translate);

function translate() {
  console.log(txtWord.value);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
}

button {
  font-size: 1em;
  background:lime
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <form>
      <input name="wordToTranslate" id="txtWord" type="text">
      <button type="button" id="btnTrans">Translate</button>
    </form>
  </body>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Note the `DOCTYPE` on the html.  Also, all of the HTML elements are lowercase and the attribute values are quoted.  JavaScript side, the event listener for the button click event is wired up in the JavaScript code, not in the HTML.  The variables are set using `const`, which is scoped differently than `var`.  I've also moved the inline styles to a CSS file and gotten rid of the old, deprecated ones like `bgcolor`.

Separating the code into separate files like this creates a clear responsibility for each part of the overall app: the HTML is the view; the CSS styles that view and can be overridden or changed in the future; the JavaScript acts as the controller.

I don't really expect this to be selected as the answer to this question; rather, it's general advice for a general question and new-to-the-web-world programmer.  Welcome aboard! =)